# Rename a file in Camel when a duplicate is found

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to rename a file in Camel when a duplicate is found. I have a directory that has x number of files and if another file is put in that folder I want the original to be renamed rather than overwritten.

I tried to use `fileExists` and `tempFileName` options but it does not solve the issue.

```
.to("file://"+decryptedFailed+"?delay=3000&tempFileName=tempName&fileExist=TryRename")
```

Is there anything wrong with how I am doing this?

Comment: How are you using `fileExist`? Provide some code.

Comment: I have just added this to the question now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/file2):

> TryRename [...] allows to try renaming the file from the temporary name to the actual name, **without doing any exists check**.

This is not what you want. Instead of `TryRename`use `Move` together with the `moveExisting` option:

```
.to("file://"+decryptedFailed+"?delay=3000&fileExist=Move&moveExisting=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}");
```

Comment: Thanks for this it now works. The only thing is that it currently puts the original file in a directory, where the name of the directory equals the moveExisting name. Is it possible to have just the file there with no directory?

Comment: @JamesFox You could use `file:onlyname`. Please see http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html for all possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Peter but this has not stopped the files being put in directories. It must be a feature of the moveExisting option. I guess I will just have to live with it.